# AngularJS $http.get results to array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using $http.get to get data consisting of MailID and SubscribedDate.
Results are assigned to $scope.subscriber . I would live to have an array of all MailID values like: `["john@msn.com","peter@gmail.com", "mike@stack.com"]`

```js
 getAll();
 function getAll() {
  var servCall = APIService.getSubs();
  servCall.then(function (d) {
   $scope.subscriber = d;
  }, function (error) {
   console.log('Oops! Something went wrong while fetching the data.')
  });
```

Comment: What's the issue? What data is returned in `d.data` ?

Comment: it's json with MailID and SubscribedDate

Comment: What is the structure of the JSON? Add a sample response in your question.

Comment: can you share the json returned by the api

Answer (score 0):

use javascript `map` function to get the email ids

```
servCall.then(function(d) {
    $scope.mailIDarr= d.data.map(o=>o.MailID);
}, function(error) {
    console.log('Oops! Something went wrong while fetching the data.')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ArrayOftbl_Subscribers xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebAPIAndAngular.Models">
<tbl_Subscribers>
<MailID>first value second value third value</MailID>
<SubscribedDate>2017-08-01T16:44:06.391</SubscribedDate>
</tbl_Subscribers>
<tbl_Subscribers>
<MailID>third value fourth value sixth value</MailID>
<SubscribedDate>2017-08-01T16:48:38.977</SubscribedDate>
</tbl_Subscribers>
<tbl_Subscribers>
<MailID>kurma</MailID>
<SubscribedDate>2017-08-01T19:55:04.355</SubscribedDate>
</tbl_Subscribers>
<tbl_Subscribers>
<MailID>belekas</MailID>
<SubscribedDate>2017-08-02T05:41:32.472</SubscribedDate>
</tbl_Subscribers>
<tbl_Subscribers>
<MailID>rerere</MailID>
<SubscribedDate>2017-08-02T05:45:06.672</SubscribedDate>
</tbl_Subscribers>
<tbl_Subscribers>
<MailID>fsdfsd</MailID>
<SubscribedDate>2017-08-02T05:45:41.483</SubscribedDate>
</tbl_Subscribers>
<tbl_Subscribers>
<MailID>1111</MailID>
<SubscribedDate>2017-08-02T06:33:37.331</SubscribedDate>
</tbl_Subscribers>
</ArrayOftbl_Subscribers>
```